# mongoose ref only returns one element inside array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to reference an array of categories but output is only returning one element inside.

here is the post model, I'm I am wondering about post_categories that has a ref to Category

here is the post model

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

mongoose.set('debug', true)

const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: false,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  post_title: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    min: 3,
    max: 160,
    required: true
  },
  post_slug: {
    type: {},
    unique: true,
    index: true
  },
  post_excerpt: {
    type: String,
    max: 1000
  },
  post_content: {
    type: {},
    required: true
  },
  post_thumbnail: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String
  },
  post_comments: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Comment',
    require: false
  }],
  post_tags: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Tag',
    require: false
  }],
  post_categories: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Category'
  }
  ],
  post_meta_title: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  post_meta_description: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  post_meta_keywords: [{
    type: String,
    required: false
  }],
  allow_comments: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
    default: 1,
  },
  allow_search_engines: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
    default: 1
  },
  published: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: false,
    default: 0
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', postSchema)

export default Post
```

this is from the post controller

```
const getPosts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await Post.find().populate('post_categories')

  res.json(posts)
})
```

this is the category model, I'm thinking the problem is within the post controller or the post model though.

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  post_count: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  }
}, {
  timestamps: true
})

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema)

export default Category
```

here is output with the populate

```
[
    {
        "post_comments": [
            "60257ffd6b08fb4334078b56"
        ],
        "post_tags": [],
        "post_categories": [
            {
                "post_count": 2,
                "_id": "602148846168c7408831ac4c",
                "name": "Category One",
                "__v": 0,
                "createdAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.647Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-02-19T05:55:45.944Z"
            }
        ],
        "post_meta_keywords": [],
        "allow_comments": true,
        "allow_search_engines": true,
        "published": false,
        "_id": "602148846168c7408831ac49",
        "post_title": "Post One",
        "post_excerpt": "Post one excerpt",
        "post_content": "This is post one content blah blah blah",
        "post_slug": "post-one",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z"
    },
    {
        "post_comments": [
            "6025e1150d215935688d68ba",
            "6025e1150d215935688d68bb"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
            "602148846168c7408831ac51",
            "602148846168c7408831ac52"
        ],
        "post_categories": [
            {
                "post_count": 2,
                "_id": "602148846168c7408831ac4d",
                "name": "Category Two",
                "__v": 0,
                "createdAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.647Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-02-19T05:55:46.053Z"
            }
        ],
        "post_meta_keywords": [],
        "allow_comments": true,
        "allow_search_engines": true,
        "published": false,
        "_id": "602148846168c7408831ac4a",
        "post_title": "Post Two",
        "post_excerpt": "Post Two excerpt",
        "post_content": "This is post two content blah blah blah",
        "post_slug": "post-two",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z"
    },
    {
        "post_comments": [],
        "post_tags": [],
        "post_categories": [
            {
                "post_count": 2,
                "_id": "602148846168c7408831ac4c",
                "name": "Category One",
                "__v": 0,
                "createdAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.647Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-02-19T05:55:45.944Z"
            }
        ],
        "post_meta_keywords": [],
        "allow_comments": true,
        "allow_search_engines": true,
        "published": false,
        "_id": "602148846168c7408831ac4b",
        "post_title": "Post Three",
        "post_excerpt": "Post three excerpt",
        "post_content": "This is post three content blah blah blah",
        "post_slug": "post-three",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z"
    }
]
```

that output only shows one category however if I show the output without populate it shows all the categories

```
[
    {
        "post_comments": [
            "60257ffd6b08fb4334078b56"
        ],
        "post_tags": [],
        "post_categories": [
            "602148846168c7408831ac4c"
        ],
        "post_meta_keywords": [],
        "allow_comments": true,
        "allow_search_engines": true,
        "published": false,
        "_id": "602148846168c7408831ac49",
        "post_title": "Post One",
        "post_excerpt": "Post one excerpt",
        "post_content": "This is post one content blah blah blah",
        "post_slug": "post-one",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z"
    },
    {
        "post_comments": [
            "6025e1150d215935688d68ba",
            "6025e1150d215935688d68bb"
        ],
        "post_tags": [
            "602148846168c7408831ac51",
            "602148846168c7408831ac52"
        ],
        "post_categories": [
            "60342fbdfb8c6a0db2aecf00",
            "602148846168c7408831ac4d"
        ],
        "post_meta_keywords": [],
        "allow_comments": true,
        "allow_search_engines": true,
        "published": false,
        "_id": "602148846168c7408831ac4a",
        "post_title": "Post Two",
        "post_excerpt": "Post Two excerpt",
        "post_content": "This is post two content blah blah blah",
        "post_slug": "post-two",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z"
    },
    {
        "post_comments": [],
        "post_tags": [],
        "post_categories": [
            "6021479b255d7a3360d4bffa",
            "602148846168c7408831ac4c"
        ],
        "post_meta_keywords": [],
        "allow_comments": true,
        "allow_search_engines": true,
        "published": false,
        "_id": "602148846168c7408831ac4b",
        "post_title": "Post Three",
        "post_excerpt": "Post three excerpt",
        "post_content": "This is post three content blah blah blah",
        "post_slug": "post-three",
        "__v": 0,
        "createdAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-02-08T14:19:48.606Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you confirm that categories with _ids: `6021479b255d7a3360d4bffa` and `60342fbdfb8c6a0db2aecf00` actually live in your Categories collection?

Comment: crap I can't believe it was that simple, I checked earlier but double checked and your right.